# Process `find` output parse out certain fields

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, text-formatting

I have find output as follows:

```
/var/data/run/stores/user.rstd/info.settings:4: Password = "xxxxxxx";
```

In this example, "user" and the value of "Password" ("xxxxxxx";) need to be redirected to a new file. the "user" will always be in the 5th directory, however I do not want the .rstd extension. My new file output should look like this

```
user   "xxxxxxxx";
```

How can I best accomplish this?

Comment: I'm trying to do this with grep but not having any luck so far. I can get the password field but can't figure out how to get the "user"

Comment: took a stab at it with sed to get just the user - sed -i -e 's/\/var\/data\/run\/stores\///g' but did not work.

Comment: @user53029 , well that is one way to approach.. you could add another substitution in the same command to get your output.. like `sed -e 's/\/var\/data\/run\/stores\///' -e 's/\..*=//'` .. once you are okay with output, you can add the `-i` flag for inplace editing.. there are many different ways the regex could be written

Comment: Is this literally just one line? Or is the find putting out many lines like this. If so, does the output go to a single file full of users, or does each `<user> "<password>"` pair go into its own file?

Answer (score 5):

### Using sed

For convenience, let's put our find output into shell variable `s`:

```
$ s='/var/data/run/stores/user.rstd/info.settings:4: Password = "xxxxxxx";'
```

Now, let's extract the parts that you want:

```
$ echo "$s" | sed -E 's|/([^/]*/){4}([^/.]*)[.][^"]*(.*)|\2 \3|'
user "xxxxxxx";
```

#### How it works

The sed script consists of a single substitute command.  The `-E` flag is used to enable extended regular expressions.

- The line is matched against: `/([^/]*/){4}([^/.]*)[.][^"]*(.*)`

  `/([^/]*/){4}` matches the first four directories.  Because of the parens, the last of these directories is saved as group 1 but we will have no use for it.

  `([^/.]*)` matches the user name without the extension.  Because of the parens, this grouping is saved as group 2.

  `[.][^"]*` matches the extension and everything up to the first double-quote.

  `(.*)` matches everything starting with the first double-quote to the end of the line.  Again, because of the parens, this is saved as group 3.
- The replacement text is `\2 \3` which means group 2 followed by a space followed by group 3.

### Using awk

```
$ echo "$s" | awk -v FS="/" '{ name=$6; sub(/[.].*/,"", name); sub(/[^"]*/, ""); print name, $0;}'
user "xxxxxxx";
```

#### How it works

- `-v FS="/"`

  This sets the field separator to `/`.
- `name=$6; sub(/[.].*/,"", name)`

  As awk counts fields, the name is in the sixth field.  We save the sixth field in the variable `name` and then remove everything in `name` after the first period.
- `sub(/[^"]*/, "")`

  This removes everything from the line up to but not including the first `"`.
- `print name, $0`

  This prints the name, a field separator (default is a space), and what's is left of the line after the substitution (the password).

Comment: If the `x`'s in `password` are meant to represent any character, will using `awk` and splitting on `FS="/"` (solidus) risk truncating passwords that contain `/` solidus ?

Comment: @jubilatious1 That is a good issue to think about.  In this case, however, the password, as opposed to the name, is caught by `sub(/[^"]*/, "")` which is a command that operates on the entire line.  Thus, the capture of the password is not affected by the value of `FS`.

Answer (score 2):

A long one... but seems working

```
$ echo '/var/data/run/stores/user.rstd/info.settings:4: Password = "xxxxxxx";'  | \
awk -F/ ' { print $6 $7} ' | awk -F"." ' { print $1, " ", $3 } ' | \
awk ' { print $1 " " $NF } '
user "xxxxxxx";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using `sed` grouping,

```
$ echo '/var/data/run/stores/user.rstd/info.settings:4: Password = "xxxxxxx";' | \
sed 's,\(^/var.*stores/\)\(user\)\(.rstd.*= \)\(.*\),\2  \4,'
user  "xxxxxxx";
```

I know it looks weird ;) alternatively you can use much simpler one

```
sed -e 's,/var/data/run/stores/,,;s,\..*=,,'
```

Comment: You could use the `r` flag (extended regex mode) to avoid having to escape parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Perl**

```perl
~$ perl -pe 's{^(\/[^/]+){4}\/(\w+)\.rstd\/[^/ ]+\hPassword\h\=\h\"(.+)\"}{$2 $3};'   file

#OR (with \x option)

~$ perl -pe 's{ ^ ( \/ [^/]+ ){4} \/ (\w+) \. rstd \/  [^/ ]+ \h Password \h \= \h \" (.+) \" }{$2 $3}x;'  file
```

---

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -pe 's{ ^ [ \/ <-[ / ]>+ ]**4 \/ (\w+) \. rstd \/  <-[ / \h ]>+ \h Password \h \= \h \" (.+) \" } = "$0 $1";'  file

#OR (much more explicitly)

~$ raku -pe 's{ ^ [ \c[SOLIDUS] <-[ \c[SOLIDUS] ]>+ ]**4 \c[SOLIDUS] (\w+) \.rstd \c[SOLIDUS]  <-[ \c[SOLIDUS] \c[SPACE] ]>+ \c[SPACE] Password \c[SPACE] \= \c[SPACE] \c[QUOTATION MARK] (.+) \c[QUOTATION MARK] } = "$0 $1";'  file
```

---

Sample Input:

```
/var/data/run/stores/user.rstd/info.settings:4: Password = "xxxxxxx";
```

Sample Output (all 4 examples):

```
user xxxxxxx;
```

---

*Perl References:*
https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick
https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre

*Raku References:*
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes-best-practices